# Idea for a class of matrix

Tags: class, matrix

Hello I'm trying to create a class for matrix of any size and then a class for square matrix (which will inherit from the first class)

So I've tried something like that:

```
public class MatrixDouble {

  private int               m_nRows;
  private int               m_nCols;
  private double[][]        m_array;

  public final void setSize( final int nbRows, final int nbCols )
  { 
    setNbRows(nbRows);
    setNbCols(nbCols);
  }

}


public class MatrixDoubleSquare extends MatrixDouble {

  public int getSize() { return super.getNbRows(); }

  public void setSize( final int size ) {   super.setSize(size, size); }
}
```

But I've a problem about the size, in the first class I need two integers and in the second class only one.

So I think I have to start in an entirely different way
Could you help me to write a good start of my classes?

I have written in Java but it's just pseudo-code at the moment.

Comment: This is perfectly fine. I don't see what your concern is.

Comment: Instead of a new class, just add a static initializer (a factory) for square matrices, or for identity matrices, etc. You only need a new class if new functionality is going to be implemented.

Comment: I don't see a language tag here

Comment: You might want to study existing matrix packages like [Jama](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) (Java) or [Fraction](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9088/Application-of-Fraction-class-Matrix-class-in-C) (C#).

Comment: Yes I have functionality only for the square matrix.

I think I just have to avoid the Square matrix to modify the number of rows or the number of columns separately.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a matrix class would require two inputs (sizes) and a square matrix would only require one. But, that wont be a problem. You can do this:

```
public class MatrixDoubleSquare extends MatrixDouble {
     public MatrixDoubleSquare(int size){
          super(size, size);
     }
....
}
```

This is just a pseudo code. It assumes you have a MatrixDouble class with a constructor[MatrixDouble(int w, int h)].

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you for answering but I wondered if it's alright because it could be a bit awkward.

I could do something like:

```
int size = 3;
MatrixDoubleSquare M = new MatrixDoubleSquare(size);
```

and then doing:

```
M.setNbRows(4);
```

with the function `setNbRows()` belonging to the class `MatrixDouble` and finally my matrix is not square :/

That's why I thought I could do a abstract class with `m_nbRows` and `m_nbCols` as members and then one class for the matrix of any size and another class for the square matrix and only the class for matrix any size would have a method `setNbRows` and `setNbCols` and the class dor square matrix would have a method `setSize` which would modify both of members m_nbCols and m_nbRows.

Sorry I see different way to do that but I have no idea which is good and which is the simplest, I'm confused.